# Crashing iOS App with [Class retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, memory-management

I am building up my app and I'm quite a noob, so please forgive my lack of information!

I'm able to crash my app in a certain set of steps to reproduce, but only sometimes. When it crashes, it does so on the main.m file with:

[image]

I've set an Exception breakpoint with "Throw" and separately with "Catch" and it doesn't actually pick up any particular line of code on where the crash occurs.

How would I find out what exactly is causing this issue, or which line(s) of code?

[image]

I am testing on an iPhone 5s and 6 Plus and it crashes on both.

**Update**

I have just been doing some testing with this and this is the workflow of the app.

I have a `UITableViewController` (called More Tab). I click on a `UIViewController` (called Themes) and there's a button there. I click on that button and it calls a `UIAlertView`. I click on the non-cancel button and it calls up another `UIViewController` (called IAP). There's a `UIButton` with the price and a `UIBarButtonItem` called Cancel. If I click Cancel, it dismisses the IAP UIViewController and goes back to the Themes UIViewController.

The `UIButton` on the IAPViewController dynamically calls the price from another `UIViewController` called Unlimited Entries.

I'm noticing the crash if I click on the Cancel button before the price has loaded on the `UIButton`.

With Zombies, the crash console shows:

```
2015-04-29 10:21:33.775 -[UnliimitedEntriesPurchase retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x174e4f4b0
```

In the `viewDidLoad` of the `IAPViewController`, I have:

```
[self.unlimitedEntriesPurchase validateProductIdentifiers];
```

I have a property created: `@property (nonatomic, strong) UnliimitedEntriesPurchase *unlimitedEntriesPurchase;` and I'm thinking this is the issue.

I hope this makes sense and helps determine what the issue could be.

It's a rare case that the user will come to the IAP and click the Cancel button (to dismiss the `IAPViewController`) BEFORE the price loads on the `UIButton`. However, it's something I'd like to fix rather than ship with that obvious issue.

**Update 2**

In my IAPViewController, I have a custom setter:

```
- (UnliimitedEntriesPurchase *)unlimitedEntriesPurchase
{
    if (!_unlimitedEntriesPurchase)
    {
        _unlimitedEntriesPurchase = [[UnliimitedEntriesPurchase alloc] init];
        _unlimitedEntriesPurchase.delegate = self;
    }
    return _unlimitedEntriesPurchase;
}
```

With setting the alloc and init in the AppDelegate, the if statement is not getting true here and so the custom delegate never gets set.

Comment: Can you tell us what steps you take when this happens?

Comment: It is hard to find. Let's read the stack trace: In application main there is a bad access. The block causing it, is a block added in com.apple.root.default-qos. This block has been added in com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit. These queues are private, AFAIK. But googling on it gives some results with big data objects. Is this a pointer? Beside this you can increase the stack trace resolution and hopefully find a hint.

Comment: Thanks Tyrian and Amin, I've just updated the question with the scenario of crashing.

Comment: More code on where you do the dynamically loading of the UIButton would help. I think you might do that asynchronously and when it completed loading and called back, the unlimitedEntriesPurchase was destroyed along with its view. So, it crashed when you tried to do something with it.

Answer (score 2):

The most probable cause is that you are firing an action to a deallocated object, you have to do that:

Product ---> Profile ---> Zombies (in instruments)

And then check in the instrument tool what is the object that is crashing.

You can reallocate the object in another place, as an example I will show you how to reallocate it in AppDelegate, first you have to add that in your AppDelegate.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UnliimitedEntriesPurchase *unlimitedEntriesPurchase;
+ (AppDelegate*) sharedDelegate;
```

And that in your AppDelegate.m

```
+ (AppDelegate*) sharedDelegate {
   return (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
}
```

The in the view controller you have to import AppDelegate.h and allocate your object like that

```
[AppDelegate sharedDelegate].unlimitedEntriesPurchase = self.unlimitedEntriesPurchase;
```

After that you can fire all unlimitedEntriesPurchase methods becouse it is never going to be deallocated, if you have any problem you can fire to [AppDelegate sharedDelegate].unlimitedEntriesPurchase

Comment: Thanks so much peig. I did that and I came up with: [UnliimitedEntriesPurchase retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x170e5fec0 in the console. In one of my VCs, I am calling: @property (nonatomic, strong) UnliimitedEntriesPurchase *unlimitedEntriesPurchase; should I change that from strong, or nonatomic to retain?

Comment: I've just updated the question with further information. I hope that helps.

Comment: Did you still need help?

Comment: I do peig. I've updated the question which pointed to where the issue is, but I'm not entirely sure what I need to do to fix this issue.

Comment: The problem is that you are firing a method when the object is deallocated,  it is possible that you dismiss the controller with the object and then fires a method to it.
You can retain it in other place.

Comment: Thanks peig - that makes sense. Where else would I retain, or allocate this object? I have a custom setter method which is allocating this.

Comment: I will edit my post to show you how to do a singleto where you can allocate your object.

Comment: Thanks so much for the update. I have tried that and updated my question with Update 2, but because of that, I am not able to set the custom delegate.

Comment: I did that and it said `An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated '_UIViewControllerOneToOneTransitionContext' object (zombie) at address` which is not in my code :(

Answer (score -4):

The solution is pretty simple but can you first answer me the following 2 questions -

1. Why are you not using ARC? If you use ARC and not manually retain/release, you will not face this problem.
2. Why are you firing another viewcontroller (UnlimitedPriceEntries) to calculate the price. ViewControllers should not be used for business logic. Instead you should write another NSObject class to do these calculations and use it inside IAP viewcontroller.

I hope this would solve your issue.